# XCode: Exception. How to detect the cause?

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

Xcode 4.6.1 with iOS 6.1.  I'm using remote database with StackMob.  Application first gives an error and after I click Play a few times, it runs fine and communicates with the server just fine.  Not sure how to detect the problem and should it a concern?

I have the following exception Break Point setup:

[image]

The application runs and then stops at the following line:
[image]

```
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email == %@", self.emailAddressField.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

so I changed the line above to:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@", self.usernameField.text];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest onSuccess:^(NSArray *fetchedObjects)
            {
```

Now when I run the program, I get the following error:

[image]

with

[image]

so I click the play button [image]

and I get the following error:

[image]

and after I click play one more time, the Application continues to run as if nothing happened?  Should I be concerned?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: I added code as much as I can, but I think I really need some pictures for illustration.

Comment: @user1107173 +1 for images!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what the exception is with a simple lldb command, once the debugger stops on the exception. Select the exception like in your thread 6 here:

[image]

And then if you are running on the simulator type:

```
po $eax
```

If you are running on the device:

```
po $r0  (for 32-bit)
po $x0  (for 64-bit)
```

You should get a description of the exception.

Comment: Learn something new everyday.  Thank you.  I'll mark as answered once my waiting period for 6 minutes end.

Answer (score 1):

You already had this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = 
    [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

So all you need is to keep going (without the breakpoint) and allow the error to log itself:

```
if (!fetchedObjects)
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
```